# controlling text input in edittext

Tags: android, android-layout, android-edittext

I have an EditText where the user can enter three words. How do I prevent the user from entering more words? The user also has to be able to erase what they've entered and enter three new words.

Comment: you need an `InputFilter`. see http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/InputFilter.html

Answer (score 0):

try using this in your xml :

```
<EditText 
...
android:maxLength="3" />
```

or this in your java code :

```
EditText input = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.your_editTextId);
InputFilter[] FilterArray = new InputFilter[1];
FilterArray[0] = new InputFilter.LengthFilter(3);
input.setFilters(FilterArray);
```